# In PHP is there any purpose to defining an array before it is used?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Consider a chunk of php code like this:

```
$example = array ( 'Location' => 'farm', 'Name' => 'billy', 'Meal' => array());
$example['Meal'] = array('Fruit' = > 'apple', 'Soup' => 'tomato', 'Drink' => 'wine');
```

Is there any benefit or reason to pre-define the 'Meal' sub array like that beforehand rather than simply writing:

```
$example = array ( 'Location' => 'farm', 'Name' => 'billy');
$example['Meal'] = array('Fruit' = > 'apple', 'Soup' => 'tomato', 'Drink' => 'wine');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no, unless you intend to examine the `$example` array between when it's created and when you add the 'Meal' sub-array.  In fact, on the 2nd line of your 1st example you're simply overwriting what you originally assigned to it.

You might do it the first way if, for example, you wanted to use Array operations on the sub-array after initially creating `$example`.  But not if you're later going to just overwrite it by assignment.

Comment: just to be clear, the second example is meant as an alternate, not supplementary snippet. the 'Meal' sub-array is only defined once in each example.

Comment: the point is, on the 2nd line of your first code block you are *overwriting* what you initially set `$example['Meal']` to, not somehow updating it.  updated verbiage of my answer slightly.

Comment: ok, that makes sense.  in that case, wouldn't the first example be less efficient by creating more unnecessary operations?

Comment: yes. it's unnecessary. you're (briefly) using more memory than needed, your code is slightly more verbose than needed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not in your case, but if you want to use that variable in an array function like `array_push()` then it does need to be declared first. It's always best practice to declare it if you know it's going to be an array anyway.

Comment: thanks, i've seen this done as in the first example again and again so i can only assume that it's like you say, 'best practice". what i'm trying to understand is why?  is there any reason other than for clarity why is it best practice?